# Getting an average color out of HSV image for Chlorophyll screening

Tags: python, opencv

I'm new to OpenCV and trying to get the average "greeness" of a leaf in a picture. I'm using a HSV format, and can't figure out how to average out the pixels that i've isolated out of the whole image after applying a threshold.

any ideas how should I do it?

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

def nothing(x):
    pass

while True:

    img = cv2.imread('leaves.jpg', 1)

    sub_img1 = img[300:417, 500:600]
    cv2.imwrite('sub1.jpg', sub_img1)

    #Transforming the img to HSV format

    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(sub_img1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    l_g = np.array([28, 52, 61])  #determining the lower limit for color thresholding (hue, saturation, value)
    u_g = np.array([59, 255, 255])     #determining the upper limit for color thresholding

    mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, l_g, u_g)
    res = cv2.bitwise_and(sub_img1, sub_img1, mask=mask)


    cv2.imshow("original", img)
    cv2.imshow("img", sub_img1)
    cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
    cv2.imshow("res", res)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if key == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you further explain what you're trying to achieve? I couldn't figure what Chlorophyll screening is. Are you looking for `cv2.mean()` function, or perhaps for dominant color algorithm?

Comment: I'm trying to achieve a way to calculate the average color of a leaf, given it's a HSV image.

Answer (score 1):

```
average_hsv = cv2.mean(hsv,  mask)[:3]
```

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: [cv2.mean()](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga191389f8a0e58180bb13a727782cd461) returns 4 value scalar in python for some reason, So i used `[:3]` to get the first 3 values. See [slicing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_indexing_and_slicing.htm) tutorial for numpy.